# AWS user Data custom ami support in amazon eks managed nodegroups

Tags: yaml

I'm not able to create node group using yaml file inside yaml file it contains bootstrap.sh to create node group, here the file

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig
metadata:
  name: ginny
  region: us-west-2
  version: '1.17'
managedNodeGroups:
- name: ginny-mng-custom-ami
  instanceType: t3.small
  desiredCapacity: 2
  labels: {role: worker}
  ami: ami-0030109261aa0205b
  ssh:
  publicKeyName: bastion
  preBootstrapCommands:
  - kubelet --version > /etc/eks/test-preBootstrapCommands
    overrideBootstrapCommand: |
    #!/bin/bash
    set -ex
    /etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ginny --kubelet-extra-args "--node-labels=alpha.eksctl.io/cluster-name=ginny,alpha.eksctl.io/nodegroup-name=ginny-mng-custom-ami,eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup=ginny-mng-custom-ami,eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup-image=ami-0030109261aa0205b"
```

```
[root@ip-1-2-3-4 eks-node-group]# eksctl create nodegroup --config-file maanged-nodegroup.yaml
Error: couldn't create node group filter from command line options: loading config file "maanged-nodegroup.yaml": error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 15: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way It should work:

```
preBootstrapCommands:
- kubelet --version > /etc/eks/test-preBootstrapCommands
overrideBootstrapCommand: |
  #!/bin/bash
  set -ex
  /etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ginny --kubelet-extra-args "--node-labels=alpha.eksctl.io/cluster-name=ginny,alpha.eksctl.io/nodegroup-name=ginny-mng-custom-ami,eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup=ginny-mng-custom-ami,eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup-image=ami-0030109261aa0205b"
```

Comment: How is this different from what OP has in the Question?

Comment: overrideBootstrapCommand should align with preBootstrapCommands